# In what type of application or scenario PL/SQL is better as back-end?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, plsql

I am a java/j2ee developer. I always like JPA/JTA or hibernate for ORM. Since it gives me portability. But for large scale application, portability is not that important sometimes. Lots of time they ask to use PL/SQL as BE. I always find it un necessary. Apart from ARRAY and scheduling etc. Cos, with PL/SQL, application logic gets fragmented in java and PLSQL.

What are business / application scenario where PLSQL is better in-terms of performance / design / maintainability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this usually depends on whether you prefer objects or relational databases.

A DBA would argue that middle tier applications come and go, but relational databases live forever.  Portability is rarely important for relational databases, especially if a firm has made a large investment in Oracle.  A decision to migrate to another vendor won't be made lightly.

A DBA may prefer stored procedures because it acts like a Java interface and shields users from the underlying schema details.  S/he can modify the schema as will as long as the stored proc parameters don't change.

Sometimes stored procedures make sense for performance reasons.  Why query for a large data set on the middle tier, process it, and put it back in the database when you can do all the calculations on the database server?

Using stored procs does force you to do maintenance on both middle tier and server, but that's a choice.

I don't believe there's a hard and fast answer that would say objects or stored procedures are always right.  If that's what you're looking for, I'm afraid you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: +1 I would say, that for dynamically configurable applications, where data consistency criteria change with the configuration, this can be very hard (almost impossible?) to do with PLSQL. (If it's complex enough to require building a sophisticated object graph dynamically in a middle-tier, how will anyone translate that into PLSQL?)

Comment: @Chris, with field level selects and the ability to return dynamic cursors, you'd be surprised how easy it is to duplicate any sort of mapping I've seen in an ORM in straight PL/SQL. Whether your ORM would be able to handle it is another question, as to performance, it depends on whether you want to buy app servers, or oracle db servers for your scaling needs.

Comment: @mezmo: I think, we mean different things here. I don't mean so much the mappings. What I mean is, that data validation and consistency rules may depend on *user* configuration. Think about a system that handles data entry for clinical studies. Every study has its complete set of own (complex, medical) user defined rules... Many modern applications contain at least some user configurable part, which impacts consistency rules.

Answer (score 1):

Put it simply PL/SQL is the closer you can get to your Oracle DB therefore performance comes first in mind in situations where you are dealing with loads of database entries.